# wp_insert post doesn't work

Tags: wp-insert-post

Here is my script :

```
$my_post = array(
                'post_title' => "post test",
                'post_date' => current_time('mysql'),
                'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_category' => array(1)

            ); 
        $post_id= wp_insert_post($my_post);
        var_dump($post_id);
```

Comment: What does your `var_dump` prints?

Comment: The default post type is `post`, the type parameter is not necessary. But maybe the date is wrong in format. Leave this param for testing or add your return message from the `var_dump()` in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the date param or use the right format for the time stamp, like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),` But it is not necessary, WP use the current timestamp on the insert post time.

Comment: Shouldn't the "y" be a capital "Y"?

Comment: Yes, there is right, see the documentation of [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

The date param is wrong. the format for the date should match the wp standards for the post. The below snippet works fine.

```
$my_post = array(
                'post_title' => "post test",
                'post_date' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_category' => array(1)

            ); 
        $post_id= wp_insert_post($my_post); 
        var_dump($post_id);
```